# Jest - How to use expect once to assert if multiple functions was called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I've been using Jest for a while, and I know that I am able to use multiples `expect` to test each function, like:

`expect(myFunction).toBeCalled();`

Therefore,  I would like to know if there is a way to test multiple functions using a single e `expect` method. Something like:

```
const logoutModalProps = {
  dismissAllModals: mockFunction,
  logoutUserDeleteState: mockFunction,
  toggleDrawer: mockFunction,
  resetToScene: mockFunction,
  popScene: mockFunction,
};

describe('when using handlers for logoutModal', () => {
  it('should call handleLogout methods', () => {
    handleLogout(logoutModalProps);
    expect(...logoutModalProps).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Note: In the case, the function `handleLogout` call all of those methods.

Is there a way to do so? If yes, please let me know. If not, should I use multiple expects or there are better ways to do?

Thanks advance

Comment: You should use mutiple expects as it will tell you where exactly your test failed, but if you have a lot of tests where you are looping through functions and expect them to be called, I would advice you to write a helper function that loops through an array you provide and runs `toBeCalled()` or any other assertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use multiple expects. If that's cumbersome to do individually, you could do them with a loop.

```
it('should call handleLogout methods', () => {
  handleLogout(logoutModalProps);
  Object.values(logoutModalProps).forEach(mockFn => {
   expect(mockFn).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```